# How to use getmxrr to get the host name, ip address of mail server?

Tags: php, email, mx-record

From the phpmanual, the getmxrr( get mx record) is a bool value, it is true if the record exist.

However, i would like to get more information about the mail domain, for example:

A simple mx lookup record (hotmail) is like this:

```
Pref    Hostname    IP Address  TTL     
5   mx1.hotmail.com 65.55.92.152    60 min  
5   mx2.hotmail.com 65.55.92.152    60 min  
5   mx3.hotmail.com 65.54.188.110   60 min  
5   mx4.hotmail.com 65.55.92.136    60 min
```

Can i obtain the above information using getmxrr?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Second parameter gives mx host list:

```
$hosts = array();
getmxrr('hotmail.com', $hosts);
var_dump($hosts);
```

[getmxrr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php)

to get and ip adresses simple request for it with [gethostbyname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php)

```
 foreach($hosts as $host) {
     echo $host . ' ' . gethostbyname($host) . '<br />';
 }
```

Comment: that means i can obtain every hostname and ip address?